# How to use webRTC specific modules in java application

Tags: java, audio, java-native-interface, webrtc, echo-cancellation

I have a simple **java application** where the application client can send/receive pure audio UDP packets to server and server will relay the audio packets to everyone except sender.

Now how can I use **webRTC EchoCancellation** module or other feature modules in my application side ?
I found that it is possible using JNI and webRTC c/c++ libraries (tried and failed) but I need a good kickstart to know which part of huge webRTC codebase should I use and how, to make this working.

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

webRTC modules are in c/c++ and it is possible to use webRTC audio processing modules to use separately in the java project.

Firstly, you can explore recent stable webRTC codes from an official source and try to understand the basic processing part in their modules. Or there are already some c/c++ projects where this type of processing modules are already separated. like for webRTC aec3(the latest echo cancel module of webrtc), you can explore [aec3 project](https://github.com/ewan-xu/AEC3)

Secondly, you have to build a bundled library from that module code which serve the purpose and exposes only necessary functions

Thirdly, you have to know about JNI(Java Native Interface) which is not so complex and a few minutes read can give you the necessary knowledge. JNI paves the way to call native library code from java and you can peacefully call your audio processing functions from AEC/NS/AGC etc modules.